Module Not Found npm
PS C:\Programming\BookStoreProject> npm install node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205   throw err;   ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli.js' Require stack:
- C:\Users\Lior Morali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1202:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1290:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:188:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lior Morali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1455:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1534:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1265:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:187:14) {          code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Lior Morali\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'   ] }

Node.js v22.0.0

Ive tried everything nothing is working :(
Tried npm install but its the same error
Tried changing the environment variables path
Please Help ME
